# UWP Packaged WPF .NET 6 app starts a blank window when launched through uri activation and execution alias

Tags: c#, wpf, msix, appxmanifest

I am trying to package a wpf application into an WPF. I use the `makeappx` executable that is packaged with Windows 10. The WPF in question is just a dummy project. All it has is a button (prototype for something else). The WPF itself works as intended when packaged.

Appxmanifest.xml file content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"
  xmlns:uap10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

    <Identity Name="WpfApp1" Publisher="CN=Something, O=Another thing, L=City, C=DK" Version="1.0.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x86" />
    <Properties>
        <DisplayName>WpfApp1</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>Something</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>Images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
    </Properties>
    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="EN-US" />
    </Resources>
    <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="MSIXCore.Desktop" MinVersion="6.1.7601.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.20348.0" />
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.19041.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.20348.0" />
    </Dependencies>
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="WpfApp1" Executable="WpfApp1.exe" EntryPoint="windows.fullTrustApplication">
            <Extensions>
                <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias">
                    <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
                        <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="WpfApp1.exe"/>
                    </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
                </uap5:Extension>
            </Extensions>
            <uap:VisualElements
                BackgroundColor="#464646"
                DisplayName="WpfApp1"
                Square150x150Logo="Images\StoreLogo.png"
                Square44x44Logo="Images\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png"
                Description="A useful description" />
        </Application>
    </Applications>
</Package>
```

I have a build pipeline task that packages the application as such:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'MSIX Packaging'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\makeappx.exe' pack /d 'path\to\output\' /p test.msix
```

It gets signed and published to artifacts. I can install it without problem. If I launch it like a normal app it works as intended, i.e. the WPF launches and everything's good. However, if I launch it through either URI activation (`WpfApp1:`) or, as shown in the example given, execution alias (`WpfApp1.exe`), it also opens a blank UI window as shown in the image below alongside the WPF application (i.e. two separate windows):

[image]

Anyone able to explain why this blank window appears when launching the app through execution alias and how to prevent the blank window from appearing?

Comment: Where is the executable "WpfApp1.exe" located in the URI?

Comment: It's in the root of the MSIX

Comment: Is WpfApp1.exe in the same folder as the Appxmanifest.xml?  The click code in the button is not running.  Something is wrong with the relative path in the code in the click button method.  Maybe the route is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're talking about. The problem isn't the app itself. The button works as intended (all it does it change the text of the button). The problem is the huge white window that starts alongside the app when it's packaged as a UWP and launched via execution alias.

Comment: The wpf data has to be loaded when page is started.  The data has to come from someplace.  It is not finding the data.

Comment: Again, I don't know what you mean here. The WPF app launches just fine. The problem is that while the WPF app launches another blank UI window appears as well, although this blank window only appears when launching the app through an execution alias.

Comment: You never said you were getting two windows.

Comment: I did, and I included an image showing the two windows, but I'll elaborate a bit in the original question to eliminate any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found the answer to this. Apparently the problem is this line:

```
<Application Id="WpfApp1" Executable="WpfApp1.exe" EntryPoint="windows.fullTrustApplication">
```

Apparently `Windows.FullTrustApplication` is supposed to be written in pascal case instead of camel case, even though [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-application#combinations-of-activation-info-attributes) consistently uses camel case. I suspect this is a bug in the framework.

So, in short, the `Application` element containing the `EntryPoint` attribute is supposed to look like this:

```
<Application Id="WpfApp1" Executable="WpfApp1.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
```

Hope this helps someone down the line because this took me days to discover because this creates no errors or warnings when building.